# defining constants like #define that can be used in switch statements in java

Tags: java, android, constants

I would like to define some constants like `#define myXYZ 1` so I can also use them in `switch` statements.

When I do the often suggested

```
public static final Integer myXYZ = 1;
```

and

```
case Constants.myXYZ:
```

I get the compiler message that `case expression must be constant`

What would be the best way of resolving this?

Thanks!

Comment: keep in mind that ´#define myXYZ 1´ is not a constant but a preprocessor macro. In modern C or C++ you are encauraged to write ´const int myXYZ=1;´

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just change it to `int` and it should be fine:

```
public static final int myXYZ = 1;
```

This is because a case value has to be a constant expression or an enum name. From [section 15.28](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5313) of the JLS (constant expressions):

> A compile-time constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following [...]

Therefore an expression of type `int` can be a constant expression, but an expression of type `Integer` can't.

If this is a set of values which makes sense as a concept on its own, then an enum would possibly make more sense.

Comment: If all problems were that easy, programming would be a really boring job.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use `int` :

```
public static final int myXYZ = 1;
```

or use `enum` constants.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch between them probably best design it to use enumeration instead